# Send image with Post Form et encoded this in based64 with node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, forms, post

i try to get an image from post form ( users on my website ) and encoded this in base64 to record in my dataBase , i try but when i get the files , that only take the name .. ("5165151.jpg")
what wrong with my code ?

```
app.post("/postCreas",(req,res)=>{
    const imgUp = new imgModel({

    })
    let title = req.body.title
    let commentaire = req.body.sujet
    let img = req.body.upload
    let postCollection = db.collection('POSTCreas')
   /* let im64= Buffer.from(img, 'binary').toString('base64')   */ 
    console.log("test :"+img) 
        
    
    
    
    postCollection.insertOne({_id:title,title:title, commentaire : [commentaire],fichiers:img})        
    res.redirect("vosCreas")                       
    res.end()    
})
```

and my form code is :

```
  app.post("/postAstuces",(req,res)=>{
    let title = req.fields.title
    let commentaire = req.fields.sujet
    let img = req.files.upload.toString('base64')
    let postCollection = db.collection('POSTastuces')
    console.log("test : "+img)
    
    
    postCollection.insertOne({_id:title,title:title, commentaire : [commentaire],fichiers:img})        
    res.redirect("vosAstuces")                       
    res.end()    
})
```

Have a good day !

Comment: You'll need to show the form code too. Chances are you're missing the proper `enctype`.

Comment: of course sorry ..

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your `<form>` tag, which is required for file uploads.

You'll also need to make sure your server knows how to parse multipart form data. How to do that depends on the way you've configured things.

Comment: ok i have add your advices like : <form action="/postCreas" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formSubject" method="post">  but now all my inputs are null when i try console.log from the result of the post ...

Comment: Refer to the second part of my answer. You will need to make sure your server knows how to parse multipart form data.

Comment: that ok i get the strings ( title , comment ) then i get my image and convert into base64 but that give me that : ���rӛ��- for every pictures .. it's normal ?

Comment: That looks like a string representation of binary data, so yeah, it could be correct (before you encode it to base64).

Comment: ok but i think it's after the encoding .. i update my code with my new parameter

Comment: I think you can just do `req.files.upload.toString('base64')` if you want the image (likely a buffer) as base64, but not knowing the libraries you're using, it's hard to say.

Comment: i have try your solution but return [object Object] i use node js for the server side . thanks you so much for your time !